# Supply a member function of base class

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
class Logic {
};

class InheritedLogic : public Logic {
    void someMember();
};

void setHandler(void (Logic::*h)(void));

setHandler(InheritedLogic::someMember);
```

This doesn't compile, because:

> Error 16  error C2664: [..] cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__thiscall InheritedLogic::* )(void)' to 'void (__thiscall Logic::* )(void)' [..]

I'd say `InheritedLogic::someMember` is of the type `Logic::*()`, but apprently not.

How can I make this work? I am looking for a way to supply a member of the `Logic` class to another class that has no knowledge of any possible inheritances, such that I can be flexible in the logic handler I can attach.

Comment: but `Logic` has no such member variable

Comment: The casting rules for member pointers miror the rules for casting object pointers but in a reverse way. Simple figure to illustrate: Derived* -> Base* implicitly, Base::*() -> Derived::*() implicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std/boost ::function` with `std/boost:: bind`.

```
void setHandler(const std::function<void()>);

setHandler(std::bind(&InheritedLogic::someMember, &object));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply try templates:

```
template <class T>
setHandler(void(*T::pFunction)(void))
```

now for the instantiation:

```
setHandler<InheritedLogic>(InheritedLogic::someMember)
```

Answer (score 1):

Member function inheritance goes the other way around.

```
struct Logic {
};

struct InheritedLogic : Logic {
    void someMember();
};

struct MoreInheritedLogic :  InheritedLogic {
};

void setHandler(void (MoreInheritedLogic::*h)(void));

int main () {
setHandler(&InheritedLogic::someMember);
}
```

This compiles. Your code does not, because the inheritance goes the wrong way.

To understand why, imagine for a second that your code is valid, and try to mentally reproduce what will happen if you call

```
Logic* l;
l->*h();
```

If the problem is not clear yet, add a data member to `InheritedLogic` and make `someMember()` access it.

Comment: I understand, in my first idea, I also supplied the object to the `setHandler` call. But that's not gonna work. The solution with `std::bind` is exactly what I was looking for.